# How to do Workspace Mappings?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying to figure out workspaces, but I am missing something because I can't get it to work.  I am developing in django, grunt/bower and less.  I have my root django folder added to workspace.  I have added mapping of `bower_components/` to `bower_components/` because the django web server isn't serving that folder, but devtools still sees a 404 when I click on less file there.  Do I have a wrong understanding of workspaces in devtools?

Here is the sources panel showing the added folder.

[image: Sources Panel]

Here is the mapping for bower_components.

[image: Mapping]